# When I open Gallery phone starts going through a Gmail installation Wizard

Tags: gallery

My friend has an Android (he's an older gentleman and not very mobile phone savy) and when he opens the Gallery, a Gmail installation screen pops up. This just started today. He doesn't have a Gmail address and doesn't want one. He simply wanted to look at a picture from his Gallery and it went to this Gmail installation screen. I've looked at it and once it lands on that screen, I can't get past it, other than creating a Gmail account, which I'm not going to do. . I was able to get to the Gallery via the attachment function in his email, and all the images are there, so I know the Gallery "content" still exists. I just have no idea why "Gallery" would point to a Gmail setup screen instead of the Gallery I personally have an iphone so I have no idea how to help him. Any help anyone can provide is appreciated.

Comment: This would be like having an iPhone but refusing to create an iTunes account...

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the "gallery" app somehow links up to google photos or any of google's services and hence it's requiesting your gmail authentication.

It is generally a rule of thumb to association an android smartphone with at least one functioning gmail account. This is what enables you to access the play store and certain other core features of the smart phone.

You may try to do one of the following:

**1. Use android's basic file explorer that is built in.**

Depending on what version of android you are in, you should be able to get to the file explorer via Settings > USB & Storage > Explore ( or simply tap on images)

**2. Install a third party gallery app**

You may try to install a third party gallery app on your phone in order to access the photos in your local storage. If you are installing it via the play store, it is again going to prompt you to sign into your google account. Consequently, you can download the apk separately and have it installed as well. You will need to  first disable unauthorized app check (settings > Security > Unknown sources (uncheck this).

Post this, you can download any gallery apk. I would recommend you download this app called Focus. It should be available in apkmirror.com. Since I'm answering this from my office, I am unable to provide you with the direct link.

You many then click on the downloaded notification in order to install the app. Should you be unable to do that for whatsoever reason, you will still be able to locate the app via android's default file manager (settings > USB & Storage > Explore --> Then nagivage to downloads directory.